# trying to display something on a form on a focusout() action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a wrong sign in a form input if the input is empty with focusout().
I tryed this, it works when the input is empty, but if I type something in it i it goes into focusout() also:

```
if(!$('#registerForm :input[name="numeInput"]').val()) {
        $('#registerForm :input[name="numeInput"]').focusout(function(){
            $('#checkNumeIcon').css({
                "color": "red",
            });
            $('#checkNumeIcon').attr("class","glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
            $('#checkNumeIcon').fadeIn();

        });
    }
```

I hope I explained good enough, it is my first post here.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: FYI, jQuery methods are designed for chaining. You can simplify and speed-up your code `$('#checkNumeIcon').css({
                "color": "red"
            }).attr("class","glyphicon glyphicon-remove").fadeIn()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#registerForm :input[name="numeInput"]').focusout(function(){
    if($('#registerForm :input[name="numeInput"]').val().length<=0) {
        $('#checkNumeIcon').css({
            "color": "red",
        });
        $('#checkNumeIcon').attr("class","glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
        $('#checkNumeIcon').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It worked! Big up for stack and his users!